# remove trail forward slashes from url with htaccess

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I have a url like `https://example.com/something`. this can have an unknown number of forward slashes at the end, so it would look like `https://example.com/something/` or `https://example.com/something//` or `https://example.com/something///` and so on. i want to remove all the forward slashes at the end of the url with htaccess. I've tried:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

and this works fine for 1 forward slash, but I can't make it generic, for any number of forward slashes. I also tried `RewriteRule ^(.*)/+$ /$1 [L,R=301]` but seems it ignores the "**+**", also tried some regular expressions but they all seem to get ignored. so basically the question is how to do a regex that actually works or if I will have to make a rule for each number of forward slashes. Also i want this rule to only be applied when `something` is in the url, if it is `https://example.com/es/` (for the language) then I need 1 forward slash at the end. Any help? Thanks!

Comment: You don't need `+` before `$` as your earlier rule also works for removing multiple trailing `/`. Make sure this is top rule and you test after clearing cache.

Comment: hi @anubhava, i was using ```https://htaccess.madewithlove.be``` to test it, and since it wasn't removing more than one i added the ```+```. are you sure it will remove all the ```/``` in the url??? thanks for the quick answer

Comment: Never test anything on `madewithlove`. It is faulty. Multiple `/` are already compressed into single `/` in `RewriteRule`

Comment: With the regex `^(.*?)/*$`, group 1 will match everything except any trailing `/` characters. So replace this expression with `$1` if you want no trailing forward slashes or `$1/` if you want one.

Comment: thanks everybody for the help. just out of curiosity, is there any tool online to test htaccess rules (something more reliable than ```https://htaccess.madewithlove.be```?? is not critic but would be helpful. thanks again!